# Laravel 5.2 With Entrust GroupRoutes Kernel.php

Tags: laravel, middleware, entrust

I am trying to add Route::group() based on a users role.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:myrole']], function () {
    //Some Routes
}
```

I am getting this error...

> Missing argument 3 for Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::handle()

I have the default install for Entrust. I am told that I need to add a line or two to the Kernel.php file in '$middlewareGroups'

What are the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the "right' way to do it was not discovered.  So I used a work around. I used @role in the blade files.  To me its a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for these I think:

```
'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
```

**Note, I have them in `$routeMiddleware`**

Then assign your roles/permissions however you see fit to a group or individual route. But store them in `$routeMiddleware`. For example:

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|owner']], function () { .. });`

Comment: I thought about that, just seemed strange to me that the install by default would not do that.  Ill give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: It's in the docs about setting it up. Not all that strange. Composer package can't install/add these lines automatically (nor would you want it too).

Comment: Remember to accept answer if it works for you. I see it's your first post - welcome!

Comment: I added it, it didn't work.  i have looked all the place in doc for info on this.  The only docs I find are for the $routeMiddleware settings.  Nothing I can find has anything to do with $middlewareGroups.

Comment: Dude...put it in the $routeMiddleware settings. You need to assign the middleware to a group or specific route manually. i.e. `Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin|owner']], function () { .. });`

Comment: Its already there! Please see original post.  I have set up my route. My $routeMiddleware array has role, permission and ability from Entrust.  Its not working.  I cant find any other documentation to make this work.

Comment: Make sure your also: `php artisan route:clear`...some stuff might be cached.